# Error: undefined local variable or method `resource_class' when installing omniauth-twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication, omniauth

I am trying to do a sign in with facebook/twitter, and following [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised?view=asciicast)

I have added the following to my config/initializers/devise.rb (where I did put in my consumer key and consumer secret as provided by Twitter).

```
config.omniauth :twitter, ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"], ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
```

After adding ":omniauthable" to my user model, The following produces this error "undefined local variable or method `resource_class' for #<#:0x007febf67af938>"

```
- if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
  - resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this by removing the "ENV[]" brackets:

```
config.omniauth :twitter, 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY', 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'
```

and defining resource_class in my application_helper.rb

```
def resource_class
  devise_mapping.to
end
```

Answer (score -3):

You'll get the same error if you run this 'program':

```
resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
end
```

You have to define resource_class somewhere.  Are you a spammer for Railscasts?  It doesn't really help to provide a link for something that costs money to see.

Comment: Ah forgive me, I have edited out some of the content I quoted from railscasts, and No I am not a spammer, I am a subscribed member and love Ryan's Videos. What could I define "resource_class" as?

Comment: A 'resource' in rails is represented by a db table.  And a 'resource_class' is probably the model associated with that table.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just posted, you need to define resource_class in your application_helper.rb